# Group Header formatting in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a group header in Crystal report and all works fine but the formatting is a bit issue with the same, I want to give some space between the left border and the name of the header, I tried everything, there are options for the text align in the Format Object, but there is no option to specify the left margin space.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way can be to give space already from the code behind. As till today, the header formatting issue is there in my crystal Report version.
So I have to do something like this.